# Calling JavaScript function inside a JavaScript module from TypeScript v2.2.1

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a JavaScript module in this way

**myJSModule.js**

```
var myJSModule = function () {
   var _public_ = {};

   _public_.foo = function () {
   }

   return _public_;
}();
```

Now I need to call it in a function in TypeScript

**myTypeScript.ts**

```
namespace Custom {

    export function foo111() {
        myJSModule.foo(); // error: "Symbol myModule can't be properly resolved"
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to call foo in *myJSModule*?

Comment: Read about how to make and import modules in typescript

Comment: @binariedMe OP may not have control over that file (e.g. loaded from CDN). @vcRobe try `window.myJSModule`.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you for your quick answer. I still get the same error "Symbol window.myJSModule can't be poperly resolved"

Comment: @vcRobe you will need to define an appropriate interface to access the global window object http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/337/how-to-declare-a-new-property-on-the-window-object-with-typescript

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith for your help. I posted an answer based on the article you suggested so anyone else having the same problem can fix it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use an [ambient declaration](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/intro.html). You can make the ambient declaration in your TypeScript file, but it is often easier to manage if you place them in separate `.d.ts` files.

In your case you might add a file called `myJSModule.d.ts`:

```
declare var myJSModule: {
    foo(): void;
}
```

This will tell the compiler that `myJSModule` exists, and has the described type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution thanks to the comment of @Jared Smith

I can cast the *window* object to *any* so I don't need to declare an interface.

**myTypeScript.ts**

```
namespace Custom {
    export function foo111() {
        (<any>window).myJSModule.foo();
    }
}
```

For more information read the article http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/337/how-to-declare-a-new-property-on-the-window-object-with-typescript

Comment: `<any>window` is the legacy way of casting, prefer `window as any` instead.

Comment: Would you please tell me why *windows as any* is the preferred way?

Comment: Mostly, because in JSX context it's impossible for the parser to know what you mean when you have something like this: `var foo = <string>bar` (Is it a cast, or opening a JSX element?)

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the module

```
declare const myJSModule : any;
namespace Custom {
    export function foo111() {
        myJSModule.foo();
    }
}
```

If you have a definition file of the JS module you can also add it to your ts configuration.